# Does Not Contain Definition for DataBind

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-IIDC3HF\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EmployeeNotifier;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Name,Salary FROM YOUR TABLE", con);

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dr;
    dataGridView1.DataBind();     // causing problem here

    con.Close();
}
```

I tried this code but this displays an error

> Does Not Contain Definition for DataBind

Comment: What type of project is this for e.g. winforms, webforms, etc.

Comment: im  working in Winforms

Comment: I don't think you need the DataBind() line - that is for webforms - try it without.

Comment: i posted answer of this question in answer section

Answer (score 1):

```
var select =q;
        var c = new SqlConnection(@"Your Connection String here ");  
        var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, c);
        var commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
        var ds = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Now i try this Code and its works really fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that the datareader must iterate over the an object
try this instead create a custome class to hold your data.like below.
If that is too much trouble use an data adaptor and use DataSets

```
List<myCustomerCLass> list = new List<myCustomerCLass>();

  con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Name,Salary FROM YOUR TABLE", con);

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
myCustomerCLass  test = new myCustomerCLass();
                test.property1 = reader["Property1"]
test.property2 = reader["Property2"]
test.property3 = reader["Property3"]
list.add(test);
            }
        }

        reader.Close();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
    dataGridView1.DataBind();     // causing problem here

    con.Close();
```